# Continuity of function at a point

Tags: limits

if $f(x)$ be continuous and diffrentiable funtion over $(a-h,a+h), a,h\in \Bbb R$. Let 
$$
F(x)= \cases{ \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)-f(a)} - \frac1{x-a}&if $x ≠a$\\\beta &if $x=a$ }
$$
when $F(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ ?what is the value of $\beta$ ?

ans: $\beta= \frac{f''(a)}{2f'(a)}$
but how it comes?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You may e.g. write it as
$$ \frac{f'(x)(x-a) - (f(x)-f(a))} {(f(x)-f(a))(x-a)} $$
and use l'Hôpital's rule twice. (It better be assumed that $f'(a)\neq 0$ and $f$ twice differentiable).

Answer (score 0):

It's
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)-f(a)}-\frac{1}{x-a}=\frac{x-a}{f(x)-f(a)}\left(\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}-\frac{f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)}{(x-a)^2}\right)$$

Using l'Hôpital's rule one gets $\frac{1}{f'(a)}(f''(a)-\frac{f''(a)}{2})$ and therefore the expected result.